# how can I fill an object based on a string most easily?

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I have this string:

```
String s = "VClass2 [id=null, provider=null, venueId=VenueID [t10=555, t1=333, id=12033], categories=[FOOD_AND_DRINK], name=מסעדת גוז׳ ודניאל , englishName=null, description=null]";
```

and this object:

```
public class VClass2 implements Cloneable, Serializable, Externalizable {

    public String id;
    public String provider;
    @Transient
    public VenueID venueId;
    @Column(name="category")
    @Serialize(StringToArray.class)
    public String[] categories;
    public String name;
    public String englishName;
    public String description;
    @Transient
    public UserInfo lastUpdatedByInfo;
```

I see they don't match exactly in structure.

How can I parse the string and fill an instance of this class most easily?

I can manipulate the input string, but how should it look like in order for the Gson parse go smoothly?

```
public class MyTest {


    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String s = "VClass2 [id=null, provider=null, venueId=VenueID [t10=555, t1=333, id=12033], categories=[FOOD_AND_DRINK], name=מסעדת גוז׳ ודניאל , englishName=null, description=null]";

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }


    @Test
    public void foo()
    {
        Venue2 venue = gson.fromJson(s, VClass2.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gson expects an input in [JSON format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). That means:

- All names must be quoted
- All string values must be quoted
- you must use `:` instead of `=`
- objects must be wrapped in `{}`
- You must omit the type names

Example:

```
{"id":null, "provider":null, "venueId":{"t10":555, "t1":333, ...
```